# html helpers ASP.NET MVC DropDownList in .aspx in VB language

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

There is very little code out there that is in VB, and i'm getting stuck all the time. Can someone tell me the VB equivalent of this C# code?

Thx...

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("WillAttend", new[] {
                                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes, I'll be there",
                                                         Value = bool.TrueString },
                                    new SelectListItem { Text = "No, I can't come",
                                                         Value = bool.FalseString }
                                    }, "Choose an option") %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks TV for pointing me in the right direction...  I struggled with nutting the array Constructer Type in VB - It was right there all the time....

Robert's on page 26 of Steven Sanderson's great book, Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework.

Many thanks.

Gordon

```
<% Using Html.BeginForm()%>
    <p>Your name: <%=Html.TextBox("Name")%></p>
    <p>Your email: <%=Html.TextBox("Email")%></p>
    <p>Your phone: <%=Html.TextBox("Phone")%></p>
    <p>
        Will you attend?
        <%=Html.DropDownList("WillAttend", New SelectListItem() { _
           New SelectListItem With {.Text = "Yes, I'll be there", .Value = Boolean.TrueString}, _
           New SelectListItem With {.Text = "No, I can't come", .Value = Boolean.FalseString} _
           }, "Choose an option")%>
    </p>
    <input  type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" /> 

<% End Using%>
```

Comment: I added an answer showing the same code in Razor syntax for Visual Basic, in case someone finds that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The VB equivalent for your SelectList should be:

```
Dim yesNo as SelectList = {
    New SelectListItem With { .Text = "Yes, I'll be there", .Value = Boolean.TrueString }, _
    New SelectListItem With { .Text = "No, I can't come", .Value = Boolean.FalseString } _
}
```

http://www.cynotwhynot.com/blog/post/Does-VBNET-have-Collection-Initializers.aspx

Comment: Thx, but how would i use this code in an aspx file? I'm reading a book and i'm trying to follow the example. The example goes like this:

<body>
<% using(Html.BeginForm()) { %>
<p>Your name: <%= Html.TextBox("Name") %></p>
<p>Your email: <%= Html.TextBox("Email")%></p>
<p>Your phone: <%= Html.TextBox("Phone")%></p>


Will you attend?
<%= Html.DropDownList("WillAttend", new[] {
new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes, I'll be there",
Value = bool.TrueString },
new SelectListItem { Text = "No, I can't come",
Value = bool.FalseString }
}, "Choose an option") %>


<% } %>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

I was coding the tutorials in the PRO ASP.NET MVC 5 book from Adam Freeman and had the same problem.

The book is in c# and I wanted to code them in VB.

This was what worked for me :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(GuestResponse) GuestResponse.WillAttend, New SelectListItem() { _
    New SelectListItem With {.Text = "Yes, I'll be there", .Value = Boolean.TrueString}, _
    New SelectListItem With {.Text = "No, I can't come", .Value = Boolean.FalseString} _
                                      },"Choose an option")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as Gordon's answer above, but in Razor syntax, instead of ASPX syntax, in case that would be helpful to someone. (It was helpful to me:-)

```
@Using Html.BeginForm()
 @<text>
    <p>Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Name)</p>
    <p>Your email: @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Email)</p>
    <p>Your phone: @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Phone)</p>
    <p>
        Will you attend?
        @Html.DropDownList("WillAttend", New SelectListItem() { _
                                            New SelectListItem With {.Text = "Yes, I'll be there", .Value = Boolean.TrueString}, _
                                            New SelectListItem With {.Text = "No, I can't come", .Value = Boolean.FalseString}}, _
                                            "Choose an option")
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" />
</text>
End Using
```